# Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected token ]

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando crear un bucle que crea un determinado números de objetos, pero no se como hacer para que en cada vuelta `var per[i]` se ha diferente y me da los errores de abajo he probado y nada, me gustaría saber si se puede crear objetos de una forma parecida con bucles

```js
class estudiante{
    constructor(name,edad,colegio,ciudad){
        this.name = name;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.colegio = colegio;
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }
}

var cant = Number(prompt("ingrese la cantidad de estudiantes:"));
for(let i = 0; i < cant; i++){
    var name = prompt("name del estudiante! ‍");
    var edad = Number(prompt("edad!"));
    var colegio = prompt("colegio! ");
    var ciudad = prompt("ciudad! ");
    var per_[i] = new estudiante(name,edad,colegio,ciudad);
}

// var per_2 = new estudiante(name,edad,colegio,ciudad);
// var per_3 = new estudiante(name,edad,colegio,ciudad);

console.log(`hola ${per_0}`)
```

**Error en la consola de chrome**

[image: error chrome consola javascript objetos bucle for]

[image: error chrome consola javascript objetos bucle for]

Comment: El código así como el mensaje de error van como texto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el nombre de la variable, no puedes asignar `i` dentro de la variable, lo que puedes hacer es guardar variable en `window` para exportarla de manera global, de manera que podemos asignarle un nombre dinámico a la variable

```js
class estudiante{
    constructor(name,edad,colegio,ciudad){
        this.name = name;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.colegio = colegio;
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }
}

var cant = Number(prompt("ingrese la cantidad de estudiantes:"));
for(let i = 0; i < cant; i++){
    var name = prompt("name del estudiante! ‍");
    var edad = Number(prompt("edad!"));
    var colegio = prompt("colegio! ");
    var ciudad = prompt("ciudad! ");
    window[`per_${i}`] = new estudiante(name,edad,colegio,ciudad);
}

// var per_2 = new estudiante(name,edad,colegio,ciudad);
// var per_3 = new estudiante(name,edad,colegio,ciudad);

console.log(`hola ${per_0.name}`)
```

Lo que está haciendo el intérprete de JS, es  guardar la variable así

```
per_[i]
```

La variable `i` no va a ser parte del nombre de la variable, por ende se aplican las reglas para el nombre de una variable

- No empieza con números
- Es alfanumérico

Y los signos `[]` no son alfanuméricos, por eso está dando un error

Comment: anythingg: muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Código propuesto:

```js
    class estudiante{
        constructor(name,edad,colegio,ciudad){
            this.name = name;
            this.edad = edad;
            this.colegio = colegio;
            this.ciudad = ciudad;
        }
    }
    
    let cant = Number(prompt("ingrese la cantidad de estudiantes:"));
    let per = [];
    let name = '';
    let edad = 0;
    let colegio = '';
    let ciudad = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < cant; i++){
        name = prompt("name del estudiante! ‍");
        edad = Number(prompt("edad!"));
        colegio = prompt("colegio! ");
        ciudad = prompt("ciudad! ");
        per.push(new estudiante(name,edad,colegio,ciudad));
    }
    
    console.log(`hola ${per[1].name}`)
```

Comentarios:

Me es confusa esta sintaxis: **`per_[i]`**

Considera que esto:

```
 var per_[i] = new estudiante(name,edad,colegio,ciudad);
```

Dentro del ciclo solo te almacenaría la última instancia creada (*en el momento que el código funcionara*)

Por lo tanto esta sintaxis es errónea desde el momento que `per` solo estaría almacenando un objeto, además de que el acceso al *ìndice* tampoco luce adecuado:

```
console.log(`hola ${per_0}`)
```

Incluso si lo modificamos por algo como esto:

```
per[0].clave
```

Nos debería indicar que esa clave no esta definida

Comentarios finales:

- Las variables las declararía por fuera del ciclo, para que no se estén generando por cada iteración
- Tu variable `per` yo la declararía como un array vacío (*posterior veremos por que*)
- Por dentro del ciclo a cada variable le asignas valores
- Haces un [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push) al array vacio agregando cada instancia generada con los argumentos deseados
- Finalmente por fuera del ciclo puedes imprimir el contenido indicando el índice del objeto y la propiedad que deseas

Comment: muchas gracias, me ayudo mucho,